# How to get the folder creation time (with milliseconds)?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I need folder creation time with milliseconds in Windows.

Comment: plz give some more information

Comment: right now in windows explorer time under data modified field is showing as 14/05/2008 14:55. But I need even milliseconds also.

Answer (score 3):

There's a fundamental problem: the filesystem doesn't store the creation time of a file, only the time the file structure was last updated.

This is true on both [Windows](http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy15.htm) (read it carefully) and [Unix](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-1.html).